# Why does AVR-GCC apparently waste 6 cycles here?

Tags: avr, avr-gcc

This line...

```
            if (thisWindowsSinceLastFlash <=1 ) {
```

...complies to this code...

```
11e8:   81 e0           ldi r24, 0x01   ; 1
11ea:   8d 15           cp  r24, r13
11ec:   38 f4           brcc    .+14        ; 0x11fc
```

Why didn't the compiler use the `cpi` like this...

```
1204:   01 30           cpi r16, 0x01   ; 1
1206:   39 f4           brcc    .+14
```

and save the cycles and space and register used by the `cp`?

Both `cp` and `cpi` seam to update the same flags and leave everything in the same state...

[image]
[image]

What am I missing?

Note that the `cp` ended up being much more expensive that just the extra cycle because it forced a `push`/`pop` sequence on `r24`, which costs an additional 4 cycles (6 cycles in total).

I am using the `AVR8/GNU C Compiler : 5.4.0` that is included with Atmel Studio 7.0

Comment: What optimization level is the compiler set to use? (`-O...` flag for the CLI, no idea how that would be configured in Atmel Studio)

Answer (score 3):

The `cpi` instruction can only compare against register `r16` or greater...

[image]

..so because the value to be compared was in `r13` ( < r16), the `cpi` could not be use.

Still leaves the question as to why the compiler did not allocate to `r24` instead of `r13` in the first place an save the cycles and the `push`/`pop` sequence on `r24`, but maybe there are other places where `r13` is used that being in the lower bank helped.

Comment: With the number and complexity of compiler optimisations, I imagine it's probably often quite difficult to say exactly why a compiler compiled code a certain way.

Comment: The compiler only can do so much on such optimisations and especially register allocation is an art on its own. Also it has been a long time since gcc5 and maybe more modern Ives perform better. Have a look at the GCC explorer (you may have to install your own to get more recent avr versions)